# How to make a marker to a location in Google Maps Activity?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm making an app with a Google Maps Activity and I want to place a marker there. How do I set a marker to a location, for example the White House, so that it opens up the info page in google maps when you press the maps button in the right corner? My code:

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(38.897677, -77.036531);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("The White House"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is answer of your question what I am perceived that actually you wants to implement a click Listener.

There are two ways to do it

```
    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener( ) {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            Toast.makeText(StoreMap.this, "Info window clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

or use this one if you are intend to direct user just by clicking on marker.

```
GoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(OnMarkerClickListener)
```

just implement as similar as above
[more details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker)

Answer (score 0):

So you want your app to search for places? Try Geocoding. Here's my super simplified search method:

```
public void onSearch(String searchLocation) {
    mGoogleMap.clear();
    List<Address> addressList = null;
    Address address = null;
    LatLng latLng = null;

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext);
    try {
        addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(searchLocation, 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    address = addressList.get(0);
    latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
    mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(searchLocation));
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
}
```

Comment: How do I get the mContext?

Comment: That is my private context. You can just replace it to this if you are putting it inside an activity, or putting it as a parameter. I can change the answer to which you prefer.